# How to disable the authorization form on the checkout page using xml

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, xml, forms

How to disable the authorization form which is located on the checkout and appears if the user is not authorized.

Need to disable completely or in the second step

[image]

Comment: using XML is probably the wrong approach. have you tried enabling quest checkout?

Comment: @PhilippSander Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

This section can be manageable from 
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/form/element/email.js`

This component is initiated on 
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

from this line 
`<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email</item>`

you should be able to manipulate it according to your requirement from these two files.